# Is it worth defining an interface for a service with a single implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mocking

In my Spring application, there's typically an interface for each service, even if there's only a single implementation, e.g.

```java
public interface FooService {
  Foo getFoo(long id)

  Iterable<Foo> findAllFoos()

  void deleteFoo(long id)
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {
    // method implementations omitted
}
```

I think this practice originated in the olden days when mocking libraries could only generate a mock for an interface. But modern mocking libraries like Mockito can mock a class just as easily as an interface, so I'm not sure if there's any practical benefit to defining an interface for (Spring/Spring Boot) services with a single implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use an `interface` for `@Service` because we can make interface public and implementation package access. So it makes the scope tighter.

```java
public interface FooService {

}

@Service
class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

}
```

But it is for service that is used like a facade only.
`Controller -> Facade Service -> other classes from Spring context`

For "other classes" from Spring context that can be used by `Facade Service` I never use interfaces.

```java
@Service
class FooServiceImpl {

    private final FooServiceHelper helper;

    @Autowired
    public FooServiceImpl(FooServiceHelper helper) {
        this.helper = helper;
    }

}
```

We can go even further and say: even we have multiple implementations, maybe better to have an abstract class or default implementation rather than an interface.